# how to add interface on gdbus object (/org/bluez/hci1) for bluez 5.35?

Tags: dbus, bluez, gdbus

I am using bluez5.35 for my application development and while debugging come across that /org/bluez/hci1 provides only 8 interfaces.(org.bluez.Adapter1, CyclingSpeedManager1, HeartRateManager1, Media1, NetworkServer1, ThermometerManager1, DBus.Introspectable, DBus.properties).

I want to use few more interfaces (for example org.bluez.Network1) that are not associated with existing setup.
Below is the snapshot of my set up (snapshot attached).

Please let me know, how can i add org.bluez.Network1 interface with /org/bluez/hci ?
Is there any configuration file that i need to change ? or any other way to achieve this goal?

[snapshot of existing bluez interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWNwK.png)

Answer (score 3):

Interface org.bluez.Network1 is not implemented by object /org/bluez/hci1, which represents the Bluetooth adapter itself.

Once you pair with a device that supports the PAN profile, Bluez will create a new object representing the paired device. This object will have a path like /org/bluez/hci1/dev_AC_DD_6E_0F_C4_B8 and it will expose interface org.bluez.Network1.